# Copy a row to another table and create new timestamp

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I would like to copy data from my users_temp table to my users_final table. The fields are identical.

Here comes my query:

```
INSERT users_final (username, password, email)
  SELECT username, password, email)
  FROM users_temp
  WHERE id=8
```

My users_final table also contains a field "stamp_created".

How do I achieve that when I copy my row from users_temp to users_final the field "stamp_created" of the newly created row will contain the current timestamp?

(Of course I do not want to copy the "stamp_created" value from my users_temp table.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current date from [the `NOW()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).  Something like this:

```
INSERT users_final (username, password, email, stamp_created)
  SELECT username, password, email, NOW()
  FROM users_temp
  WHERE id=8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value and set as not nullable to stamp_created field in users_final table.